# Does adding a zero column change the matrix behavior? Can we add a zero column to a matrix so that it can be multiplied to another matrix?

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have two matrices \begin{gather} A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}, 
 B = \begin{bmatrix} e \\ f \\g \end{bmatrix} 
\end{gather} I understand that A X B is NOT defined. Can I add a zero column to A so that I can mulitply? Does it change the behaviour of matrix A? While solving a system of equation adding a zero variable doesn't change it right?

Comment: When you "add" a new column to Matrix $A$ , you are implicitly claiming no Change in Data or no loss of Data , whereas , the multiplication is losing the value of $g$. Instead , you can achieve the Same thing by "truncating" Matrix $B$ by a "row" to get new $B=[ e , f ]$ which will allow $A \times B$. By "truncating" , you can explicitly claiming loss of Data , hence that will be better & still give the Same Values.

Comment: @Prem  It kinda makes sense to explicitly mention which element to omit by changing B. Thanks for the insight.